# How to show percentage graphically in Android?

Tags: android, material-design, percentage

I'm working on a Material Design Android app about probability theory and statistics. There is a list of different events and some statistics about them in percent. I'm pretty bad in explanations, so there is a rough example: "probability that you will have children is 85%", based on data gathered from users. I need a way to show graphically the ratio: 15/85, there are always only two vales (yes/no). My idea is to make a rectangle, divided into two parts, one representing "yes" and another "no". This graphical representation of percentage is one of the key ones in the Fragment, so it shouldn't be as small as progress bar, for example.
[This is a mockup I made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUwn6.jpg), of course it's a bit of an overkill, but you get the idea.

My concern is the way of doing it. First thing that came up to my mind was making a horizontal `LinearLayout` with `weightSum="1"` attribute with a couple of coloured views in it, which will have their own `layout_weight's` (in this case 0.15 and 0.85). Another idea is to make two bitmaps with sizes representing their values, but, I assume, it will be more complicated since I will have to get device measurements to make images properly sized.

So, my questions are the following:

1. Is my idea with `LinearLayout` bad?
2. Are there any better ways of making this rectangle?
3. Any other ways of representing ratio of two values graphically?
4. Since it is the Material Design app, what style should I apply to the rectangle (or anything else)? Should it have elevation and/or rounded corners?

Comment: You can use this library for any kind of chart and graph display https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Comment: @WISHY I feel like it's too complex for such a simple situation where I have only two values. Thanks anyways, now I know what to use if there will be more values in the chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the linear layout's weight attribute will help you achieve a quick and easy solution to your problem.  MPChart does have some utilities you can use for animating your ratios, but it might be an overkill and I am not sure if it offers you the flexibility you require in your UI

Comment: I don't actually need to animate anything there, and if I needed to, I would just use standard animations. Thanks for the answer, I think I'll go with `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Cheers, and feel free to upvote people who replied to your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try PercentLinearLayout in android support library.It's support percentage layout. You can add **compile 'com.android.support:percent:22.2.0'** in your build file to add it to your application.

Comment: Thank you for this, but why use this library when it is much quicker and easier with `layout_weight`?

Comment: layout_weight can only use in LinearLayout.Percent Layout support library can use in multiple layout types.For example PercentRelativeLayout,PercentFrameLayout etc.